# Error in SQL case statement when trying to create binary flag?

Tags: sql, select, case, ssms

Here's my query where I'm testing my case structure:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CASE 130
WHEN '000000000000000' THEN '0'
WHEN '' THEN '0'
WHEN 'XXX' THEN '0'
WHEN 'RETIRED' THEN '0'
WHEN 'STUDENT' THEN '0'
ELSE '1'
END AS employed_flag
INTO #employedbeta
FROM CreditBureau.Experian
```

I'm just trying to make a new temporary table, but I'd like my case to work first. I keep getting the error:

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'XXX' to data type int.

In the database, the column 130 is a char, and I don't know why it thinks I want to make it a number. SQL server management studio, if it matters.
The column name is 130, I left the '1' off because I rewrote it here but I get the error regardless in my actual query.

Comment: Tag properly!!!  MySQL <> SQL Server!!!  Which one is this????

Comment: `THEN '0'` and `ELSE 1`?  Do you want a string or an integer?  Change the `'0'` to `0` or the `1` to `'1'`

Comment: What is `130`???  You are comparing `INT` to `VARCHAR`.

Comment: `CASE 130 WHEN` doesn't check "column 130", it checks the literal value `130`.  And since `130` is an integer `WHEN 'XXX'` is being treated as `WHEN CAST('XXX' AS INT)` to ensure the comparison is made on the same data type.

Comment: I rewrote the query, else '1' is in the actual one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`130` is an integer literal. If that's really the column name, you'll have to escape it using double quotes. As a side note, you should probably return the same type (char) in the `else` branch too:

```
CASE "130"
WHEN '000000000000000' THEN '0'
WHEN '' THEN '0'
WHEN 'XXX' THEN '0'
WHEN 'RETIRED' THEN '0'
WHEN 'STUDENT' THEN '0'
ELSE '1'
END AS employed_flag
```

Comment: the column name is 130

Comment: @CapnShanty then you need to escape it. See my edited answer.

Comment: Ah very good that fixed the whole damn query thanks, dunno why I didn't need to do that in my other queries using this table. Much thanks

Answer (score 0):

`130` is a really bad column name.  But, I would simplify the logic to:

```
SELECT TOP 1 (CASE WHEN [130] IN ('000000000000000', '', 'XXX', 'RETIRED', 'STUDENT')
                   THEN 0 ELSE 1
              END) AS employed_flag
INTO #employedbeta
FROM CreditBureau.Experian;
```

Note that I also changed the `employed_flag` to a numeric value rather than a string.  That makes more sense to me.